# Convert java code to php

Tags: java, php

I need covert this code to php.And I have some problem.

For test:
In "test"
Out "98f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6"

```
public static String a(String paramString)
    {

      try
      {
        MessageDigest localMessageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        localMessageDigest.update(paramString.getBytes());
        byte[] arrayOfByte2 = localMessageDigest.digest();
       String str = new BigInteger(1, arrayOfByte2).toString(16);
         return str;
      }
      catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException localNoSuchAlgorithmException)
      {
       return "";
      }
    }
```

Comment: This is stackoverflow.com not java2phpconvertion.com :)

Comment: Well said @ShankarDamodaran; user : please try with you code and post only for the error you facing so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do at least some sort of research before asking here. Anyway, because this is too easy, here is the solution:

```
function a($s) {
    return ltrim(md5($s), "0");
}
```

`a("test")` returns *98f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6*, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want something like this:

```
function a($paramString)
{
    return substr(md5($paramString), 1);
}

a("test"); // 98f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
```

*NB: Stack Overflow is normally used for help with problems that you have already attempted, not for people to simply write code for you*